# What are the differences between 'Amon' and 'Emon' Table IDs in CMIP6?

Tags: climate-models, climate-data

While looking for atmospheric data in CMIP6, I came across two Table entries: `Amon` and `Emon`, both seem to contain monthly-mean atmospheric data. For Example, the following two datasets are the same except for the Table ID:

1. `CMIP6.HighResMIP.EC-Earth-Consortium.EC-Earth3P-HR.hist-1950.r1i1p2f1.Amon.ta.gr`
2. `CMIP6.HighResMIP.EC-Earth-Consortium.EC-Earth3P-HR.hist-1950.r1i1p2f1.Emon.ta.gr`

The documentation doesn't mention much about the differences between those two Table IDs except that `Amon` is *Monthly atmospheric data* and that `Emon` is *Monthly (time mean, extension)*. After some searching, it seems that `Emon` has more vertical levels (27 as opposed to 19 in `Amon`).
I would like to if there are any other differences between these to Table IDs other than the difference the number of vertical levels?

Answer (score 2):

The `miptable` `Emon` is the extended variable list, which is basically there to stop the large number of more niche, rarely-used variables from cluttering the core monthly tables like `Amon`, `Omon`, `Lmon`, etc.  See the comment in the [Data Request Record](https://clipc-services.ceda.ac.uk/dreq/u/MIPtable::Emon.html):

> Data in the 'E...' tables is requested by specific endorsed MIPs, and is generally more specialised than other tables.

The variables in `Emon` tend to have priorities 2 and 3, whereas those in the core monthly lists tend to have priority 1.

I can't see any difference in the definitions of `Amon.ta` and `Emon.ta` other than the pressure levels, e.g., they are both monthly time means.  As always, check the metadata for the files you're using in case a modelling center has done something different from the Data Request.